# Erro de português no title do "wiki da comunidade"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

O seguinte texto é apresentado em uma resposta "wiki da comunidade"

> "Esta publicação pertence à comunidade desde XXX mins atrás. Os votos não geram reputação e podem ser editados por usuários com reputação de 100"

"os votos podem ser editados"??

Ficaria mais coerente

> "Esta publicação pertence à comunidade desde XXX mins atrás. Os votos não geram reputação e essa resposta pode ser editada por usuários com reputação de 100."

Como ainda não conheço o SO muito bem, ai vem minha pergunta. Eu não me lembro de reputação mínima para editar um post. O "wiki da comunidade" pode ser editado por qualquer pessoa porém somente usuário com 100+ não precisa de aprovação?

Se a resposta for **sim**, colocaria algo como:

> "Esta publicação é comunitária desde XXX mins atrás. Os votos não geram reputação. Os usuários com reputação de 100 podem editar sem necessidade de aprovação, os que possuem reputação menor deverá aguardar a aprovação."

Comment: Talvez existam alguns erros por conta da formatação automática de data, mas a correcão foi feita com base nas sugestões apresentadas